# useState is not updating my state on mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

i'm trying to change my state on mount using react hooks but the state is not updating
i have tried using a callback in setData and tried passing the array directly

code :

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
useEffect(() => {
    setData(() => {
      return [...mockData];
    });
  }, []);


return (
        <ul id="list-items">
          {data.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li
                key={index}
                id={index}
                item={item}
                className="items"
                onClick={(e) => handleShowArticle(e)}
              >
                <Card
                  eleName={item.name}
                  image={item.img}
                  footer={true}
                  footerContent={[
                    ["Price", item.price + "$"],
                    ["Date", item.published],
                  ]}
                />
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
)

const mockData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Sprinter",
    model: "Dodge",
    options: "option2",
    desc: "Praesent blandit. Nam nulla. Integer pede justo, lacinia eget, tincidunt eget, tempus vel, pede.\n\nMorbi porttitor lorem id ligula. Suspendisse ornare consequat lectus. In est risus, auctor sed, tristique in, tempus sit amet, sem.",
    price: "$67141.07",
    img1: "http://dummyimage.com/193x100.png/5fa2dd/ffffff",
    img2: "http://dummyimage.com/119x100.png/cc0000/ffffff",
    published: "4/8/2020",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Wrangler",
    model: "Jeep",
    options: "option2",
    desc: "Fusce posuere felis sed lacus. Morbi sem mauris, laoreet ut, rhoncus aliquet, pulvinar sed, nisl. Nunc rhoncus dui vel sem.\n\nSed sagittis. Nam congue, risus semper porta volutpat, quam pede lobortis ligula, sit amet eleifend pede libero quis orci. Nullam molestie nibh in lectus.",
    price: "$47054.29",
    img1: "http://dummyimage.com/238x100.png/dddddd/000000",
    img2: "http://dummyimage.com/231x100.png/ff4444/ffffff",
    published: "11/1/2021",
  },...];
```

mockdata is an array that exists on the same file as my component

Comment: please add: the code you use to validate that it is not updating and `mockData`.

Comment: add code about mockData.

Comment: If it's possible (i.e. if you're not making an API call to get the data), why don't you change the value of the initial state? `const [data, setData] = useState(mockedData);`

Comment: what's the problem again? see codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-feistel-bze1o?file=/src/App.js seems to work just fine...

Comment: `mockedData` doesn't look like it is defined within the scope of your React component. Either define `mockedData` above your component definition, or within it

Answer (score 0):

try to use this -

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    setData([..mockData]);
}, [mockData]);
```

Comment: nope plus i don't get the point of putting mockData as a dependency